# Locating the SQLite DB file on Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am working on Android application. I have implemented SQLite. Whenever I run the app on emulator I can check the DB file under data folder and I can check the values inserted into it.

But when I run the app on real device I can not find the DB file where it is situated. I have also set permissions in manifest

```
 uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
```

Please help me to find the DB file when I run the app on real device.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database is in the same location as on the emulator. However the data map is not visible for you on a phone. So work with the emulator to test databases.